# regex in js, match pattern except keywords

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I m trying to found a regex pattern in js

```
Any_Function() //match : Any_Function(
butnotthis() //I don't want to match butnotthis(
```

I have this pattern : `/([a-zA-Z_]+\()/ig`

and would like something like 
`/(not:butnotthis)|([a-zA-Z_]+\()/ig` (don't try this)

Demo here :
http://regexr.com/38qag

Is it possible to don't match keywords ?

Comment: What makes "butnotthis" something that you don't want?

Comment: Run two regexps and weed out the stuff you don't want in the second one...

Answer (score 2):

The way I interpreted your question, you wanted to be able to create a blacklist of ignored functions.  As far as I know, you cannot do this with regular expressions; however, you could do it with a bit of JavaScript.

I created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DQN79/

```
var str = "Any_Function();butnotthis();",
    matches = [],
    blacklist = { butnotthis: true };
str.replace(/([a-zA-Z_]+\()/ig, function (match) {
    if (!blacklist[match.substr(0, match.length - 1)])
        matches.push(match);
});
console.log(matches);
```

In this example, I abused the `String#replace()` method because it accepts a callback that will be fired for each match.  I used this callback to check for blacklisted function names - if the function is not blacklisted, it will be added to the matches array.

I used a hashmap for the blacklist because it is programmatically easier, but you could also use a string, array, etc.

Comment: Great but I try to find the regex for another script :
https://github.com/LeaVerou/prism/blob/gh-pages/components/prism-clike.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is one working version:

```
^(?!(butnotthis\())([a-zA-Z_]+\()/ig
```

specific the list of functions to be ignored within the braces

http://regexr.com/38qb8

For Javascript:

```
    var str = "Any_Function();butnotthis();",
        matches = [],
        blacklist = ["butnotthis"];
// Uses filter method of jQuery
        matches = str.match(/([a-zA-Z_]+\()/ig).filter(
        function (e) {
        var flag = false;
        for (var i in blacklist) {
            if (e.indexOf(blacklist[i]) !== 0) flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    });
    console.log(matches)
```

jsBin : http://jsbin.com/vevip/1/edit

Comment: Yes, the regex doesn't match all patterns. But the javascript will match all patterns

Answer (score 0):

You can establish a convention between functions and keywords, where the functions should start with uppercase letter. In that case the regex would be:

```
/(^[A-Z][a-zA-z_]+\()/ig
```